# How can I change H1 title in categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, page-title

I need to change the **h1 title** using **Custom Layout Update** field in the category edit view

How can I do this? Change many categories h1 titles without change the category name?

Comment: Can this also be done for sub-categories?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136652)

Comment: The code can't be found in my template (it is in the default, not in mine).
Can you assist me? Here's my view.phtml <?php /** * Magento * * NOTICE OF LICENSE * * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0) * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt. * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL: * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140864)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140864)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Magento 1.

This solution tested on Magento 1.9.2.3.

Here is what you can try:

**1 -** In category **Custom Layout Update**:

```
    <reference name="category.products">
      <action method="setAltName"><value>new h1 name</value></action>
    </reference>
```

**2 -** In this file below replace the code to add the `H1` tag.

**File:** `app/design/frontend/[yourPackage]/[yourTheme]/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`

**Content to change:**

```
    <h1><?php if($this->getAltName()):?><?php echo $this->getAltName() ?><?php else: ?><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?><?php endif; ?></h1>
```

**3 -** Clear Magento cache.

This solution uses `AltName` for `H1` and if it is not set it uses category name.